# Upgrading to Entityframework 6. Load() method not longer available

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am upgrading an ASP.Net webapp to Entityframework6.

I have a property on a partial class that previously used the .load() method to lazy load related entities.  The load method is no longer available in EF6 and I would prefer to keep the fact that the related entities loaded state within the class and not have the consuming code worry about the loading.

```
public partial class Member
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Has the member got a valid membership renewal
    /// </summary>
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public bool CurrentMember
    {
        get
        {
            this.Renewals.Load();     // this is no longer available in EF6
            var query = from renewal in this.Renewals
                        where renewal.Expired == false
                        select renewal;
            return (query.Count() > 0);
        }
    }
```

How can I keep the existing functionality?

Comment: Dupe -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605682/dbsetentity-load-function-missing-in-ef-6-0

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, though similar. This question is specific to properties on partial classes.

Comment: @simon831 but there is a solution there, doesn't it work?

Comment: for the love of jon skeet - the answer is there.  In EF6 the class containing extension methods was renamed from DbQueryExtensions to QueryableExtensions but the .Load() method is still there. If you are not calling this extension method directly the rename should not matter to you.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti   No.  I'm not sure if any of these answers would have fixed the original questioners problem.  But what I am doing is within a partial class that extends the generated class.   So there is no dbcontext available - which is what these answers seem to be pointing at.

Comment: @simon831 you're right (and solution to call ToList()...well I'd avoid, if possible).